# How to send Realtime notification to specific email id on Google Chat App using App Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-chat

I am creating one Google Chat App for my organization which basically have 3 stack holders such as EMP (Employee), RM (Reporting Manager) and FM (Finance Manager).

In this app, EMP can create a leave request and app will store the entry of this on a Google Sheet with leave request status `pending`.

I have tried creating a trigger that always checks the google sheet for any pending entry and accordingly sends that entry request to the corresponding Reporting Manager on google chat app.

But trigger is getting trigged but I am not able to target specific person to send this notification.

Any idea how can I do it ?

I read almost all google chat docs, but not getting this specific solution.

Comment: Try searching SO for google chat app.  There's about 75 references to it.

Comment: @Cooper Sorry but I am quite new to App Script and chat app so I don't understand these terminologies like SO. I searched it on the internet, but all results are about Google Chat getting started. can you please share some resources here in which I can check how to send messages on specific events to a specific person?

Comment: SO stands for stackoverflow OP stands for Original Poster AFAIK stands for As Far as I know

Comment: I've never used chat and I have no interest in it.